# Plotly error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-science

I'm getting the following error as soon as I try to create a Plotly graph. I tried plotting different data series and the problem doesn't seem to be them. The code breaks as soon as I try to create a figure. I tried reinstalling Plotly but that didn't help. Is it possible that I'm missing a dependency or something else?

Any clue what's causing this and how it can be fixed?

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

date = [2011,2012,2013,2014]
approved_limit = [100,200,150,400]

fig= go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name='Approved Limit',
    x=date,
    y=approved_limit,
    marker=dict(color="red"),
    line=dict(width=1),
    mode='lines',
    showlegend=True
))
fig.show()
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1348-73cd557bee68> in <module>
      5 approved_limit = [100,200,150,400]
      6 
----> 7 fig= go.Figure()
      8 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
      9     name='Approved Limit',

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\_figure.py in __init__(self, data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    594             is invalid AND skip_invalid is False
    595         """
--> 596         super(Figure, self).__init__(data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    597 
    598     def add_area(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in __init__(self, data, layout_plotly, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    631         # --------
    632         # ### Check for default template ###
--> 633         self._initialize_layout_template()
    634 
    635         # Process kwargs

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in _initialize_layout_template(self)
   2519                     else:
   2520                         # Name of registered template object
-> 2521                         template_object = pio.templates[pio.templates.default]
   2522                     self._layout_obj.template = template_object
   2523                 finally:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_templates.py in __getitem__(self, item)
     87                         "package_data", "templates", template_name + ".json"
     88                     )
---> 89                     template_str = pkgutil.get_data("plotly", path).decode("utf-8")
     90                     template_dict = json.loads(template_str)
     91                     template = Template(template_dict, _validate=False)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

**Solution:**
Installing the 'six' library and/or restarting the Jupyter kernel fixed the problem.

Comment: Looking at the traceback, `pkgutil.get_data("plotly", path)` is a `NoneType` object. This would indicate that a string is expected but None is being received. Can you include more of your code as well as a sample of the DataFrame you are creating a scatter plot from? This would help anyone trying to debug your issue, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Derek. I added the complete code. The code breaks as soon as I try to create a plotly figure. It doesn't even reach the stage of reading the DataFrame.

Comment: @AlexanderGavrailovLive - I have ran your code 3 times and its working fine for me. Can you restart your jupyter kernal or python code and try it? Otherwise share more details about OS, Python & Plotly version please

Comment: Sam, restarting the Jupyter kernel actually eliminated that error. I still have no idea what may have caused it but it's fixed now. Also before restarting the kernel I installed the 'six' library as I read it's needed. That may also have been the issue. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AlexanderGavrailovLive if the error is resolved, then you can consider [adding your own answer and accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that other people with the same issue can resolve their issue the same way you did!